# JavaScript run function keydown

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I cant find an answer to this that I understand.
I want with JavaScript (not jQuery) to make it so if the  with the id boxFilm is visible and I click on "SPACE" (keycode 32), the function togglep(); runs.

How do I do this? I've tried many things but haven't succeeded :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function togglep(){
    alert("Hi");
}

document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if(keycode === 32){
        togglep();
    }
}
```

try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GuvRP/1/